# How can I alter the values of certain rows in a column, based on a condition from another column in a dataframe, using the ifelse function?

Tags: r

So I have this first dataframe (fish18) which consists of data on fish specimens, and a column "grade" that is to be filled with conditions in an ifelse function.

```
species          BIN                                  collectors                          country grade species_frequency
1   Poecilothrissa congica BOLD:AAF7519                                 mljs et al, Democratic Republic of the Congo    NA                 2
2    Acanthurus triostegus BOLD:AAA9362 Vinothkumar S, Kaleshkumar K and Rajaram R.                            India    NA                54
3 Pseudogramma polyacantha BOLD:AAC5137                            Allan D. Connell                     South Africa    NA                15
4   Pomadasys commersonnii BOLD:AAD1338                            Allan D. Connell                     South Africa    NA                12
5       Secutor insidiator BOLD:AAB2487                            Allan D. Connell                     South Africa    NA                18
6      Sebastes macdonaldi BOLD:AAJ7419                                Merit McCrea                    United States    NA                 3
  BIN_per_species collector_per_species countries_per_species species_per_bin
1               2                     1                     1               1
2               1                    21                    15               1
3               3                     6                     6               1
4               1                     2                     1               1
5               4                     5                     4               2
6               1                     1                     1               1
```

And after filling the grade column I have something like this (fish19)

```
           species          BIN                                  collectors                          country grade species_frequency
1   Poecilothrissa congica BOLD:AAF7519                                 mljs et al, Democratic Republic of the Congo     D                 2
2    Acanthurus triostegus BOLD:AAA9362 Vinothkumar S, Kaleshkumar K and Rajaram R.                            India     A                54
3 Pseudogramma polyacantha BOLD:AAC5137                            Allan D. Connell                     South Africa     C                15
4   Pomadasys commersonnii BOLD:AAD1338                            Allan D. Connell                     South Africa     A                12
5       Secutor insidiator BOLD:AAB2487                            Allan D. Connell                     South Africa     E                18
6      Sebastes macdonaldi BOLD:AAJ7419                                Merit McCrea                    United States     B                 3
  BIN_per_species collector_per_species countries_per_species species_per_bin
1               2                     1                     1               1
2               1                    21                    15               1
3               3                     6                     6               1
4               1                     2                     1               1
5               4                     5                     4               2
6               1                     1                     1               1
```

Both dataframes have many specimens belonging to the same species of fish, and the thing is that the grades are suposed to be assigned to each species for every specimen of that species. The problem I'm having is that some rows belonging to the same species are having different grades, specially in the case of the grades "C" and "E". What I want to incorporate into my ifelse function is: Change from grade "C" to "E" every occurrence of the dataframe where two or more specimens belonging to the same species are assigned "C" in one row and "E" in another row. Because if one species has grade "E", every other row with that species name should also have grade "E".

So far I've tried the %in% function and just using "=="

Trying with %in%

```
assign_grades=function(fish18){
  fish19<-fish18 %>%
    mutate(grade = ifelse(species_frequency<3,"D",ifelse(BIN_per_species==1 & (collector_per_species>1 | countries_per_species>1),"A",ifelse(BIN_per_species==1 & collector_per_species==1 | countries_per_species==1,"B",ifelse(BIN_per_species>1 & species_per_bin==1,"C",ifelse(species_per_bin>1,"E",ifelse(fish19$species[fish19$grade=="E"]%in%fish19$species[fish19$grade=="C"]==TRUE,"E",NA))) ))))
  assign('fish19',fish19,envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
assign_grades(fish18)
```

Trying with "=="

```
assign_grades=function(fish18){
  fish19<-fish18 %>%
    mutate(grade = ifelse(species_frequency<3,"D",ifelse(BIN_per_species==1 & (collector_per_species>1 | countries_per_species>1),"A",ifelse(BIN_per_species==1 & collector_per_species==1 | countries_per_species==1,"B",ifelse(BIN_per_species>1 & species_per_bin==1,"C",ifelse(species_per_bin>1,"E",ifelse(fish19$species[fish19$grade=="E"]==fish19$species[fish19$grade=="C"],"E",NA))) ))))
  assign('fish19',fish19,envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
assign_grades(fish18)
```

Both these two options did not work and the output of this alteration should be that if one occurrence of a specific species name has the grade "E" assigned to it, so should all other occurences with that same species name.
I'm sorry if this was confusion but I tried to be as clear as I could, thank you in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a long winded answer, but:

```
dat = data.frame('species'=c('a','b','c','a','a','b'),'grade'=c('E','E','C','C','C','D'))
dat %>% left_join(dat %>% 
                    group_by(species) %>% 
                    summarize(sum_e = sum(grade=='E')),by='species')
```

Then you could do an ifelse for sum_e>0